# Docker, how to run .sql file in an image?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, dockerfile

It's my first time working with Docker an I am not sure if I am doing things well.

I have a rails applications that depends on a **Mysql** database, so I've configured the `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```
db:
  image: library/mysql:5.6
  environment:
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
  expose:
    - "3306"
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"

rails-app:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  environment:
    RAILS_ENV: development
  links:
    - db
  volumes:
    - ".:/home/app"
  volumes_from:
    - bundle

  ... omitted lines ...
```

Then, if I run the following:

```
$ docker-compose run db mysql --host=$DOCKER_LOCALHOST --port=3306 --protocol=tcp -u root < shared/create_common_tables.sql
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.99.100' (111)
```

This sounds normal, because I suspect that I have to `build` before some container that links to `db`.

I know this because if I run this in this order:

```
$ docker-compose build rails-app
$ docker-compose run -e RAILS_ENV=development rails-app bundle
$ docker-compose run -e RAILS_ENV=development rails-app bundle exec rake db:create
$ docker-compose run db mysql --host=$DOCKER_LOCALHOST --port=3306 --protocol=tcp -u root < shared/create_common_tables.sql
```

It works fine.

**But, how can I do to execute this sql before creating any container?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can load the sql file during the `build` phase of the image. To do this you create a `Dockerfile` for the `db` service that will look something like this:

```
FROM mysql:5.6
COPY setup.sh /mysql/setup.sh
COPY setup.sql /mysql/setup.sql
RUN /mysql/setup.sh
```

where `setup.sh` looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
service mysql start
mysql < /mysql/setup.sql
service mysql stop
```

And in your `docker-compose.yml` you'd change `image` to `build: ./db` or the path where you put your files.

Now this works if you have all your sql in a raw `.sql` file, but this wont be the case if you're using rails or a similar framework where the sql is actually stored in code. This leaves you with two options.

1. Instead of using `FROM mysql:5.6` you can use `FROM your_app_image_that_has_the_code_in_it` and `apt-get install mysql ...`. This leaves you with a larger image that contains both mysql and your app, allowing you to run the ruby commands above. You'd replace the `mysql < /mysql/setup/sql` with the `rails-app bundle exec rake db:create` lines. You'd also have to provide an app config that hits a database on `localhost:3306` instead of `db:3306`
2. My preferred option is to create a script which exports the sql into a `.sql` file, which you can then use to build your database container. This is a bit more work, but is a lot nicer. It means that instead of running `rails-app bundle exec rake db:create` you'd just run the script to load a db.

Such a script would look something like  this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
docker-compose build rails-app
docker run -d --name mysql_empty mysql:5.6
docker run --link mysql_empty:db -v $PWD:/output project_rails-app export.sh
```

where `export.sh` looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
RAILS_ENV=development
rails-app bundle exec rake db:create
mysqldump > /output/setup.sql
```

You could also replace the `docker run` script with a second compose file if you wanted to.

Comment: MySQL docker image already has a mechanism to initialize a new container with data. It loads all .sh and .sql files from /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d, you just need to COPY or mount from host to that directory. See https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ under "Initializing a fresh instance"

Comment: Yes, but that mechanism doesn't not fit the requirement in the question " how can I do to execute this sql before creating any container". Personally I don't think loading fixtures as part of the entrypoint is a good solution. It requires you to repeat the process every time you create the container, which slows down the startup time considerably.

Comment: Like dnephin said. I like the solution, that the image executes the scripts, so that the user only need to get the latest version of the image to save time on startup of the container. With the mysql docker image, you can't do that, cause everytime the container is started, the docker-entrypoint.sh is executed. Look in the script, you will see, that the database dirs are created in it. Everything you try to do with mysql in the image will be deleted. In my opinion, the only way is NOT to use the mysql docker image and do it on your own.